# Cannot make a comment that contains the characters "-1"

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, down-votes

I was trying to comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387959/java-double-with-a-char). I did not downvote the question, but the comment was rejected on the grounds that I should not comment on my downvote. I was using `-1` in the context of the question which was about the difference between `-1.0d` and `-1.0` in java.

Is it possible to improve this filter to not block such comments if the user has not downvoted the question, and/or not block `-1.0`?

Screenshot demonstrating the issue:
[image]

Copy pasteable comment text:

```
"-1.0f" is a float, while "-1.0d" is a double.
```

Comment: Hmm, I think the -1 actually works for a single vote deletion? Was there an error or did it vanish? If there was an error, got a screenshot?

Comment: Try adding some other word in front of -1

Comment: @JourneymanGeek screenshot added

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche it's probably site-specific.

Comment: this limitation is [only at Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283953/839601) and over there, it can be worked around by making comment length longer than 120 chars

Comment: @gnat over on SE HQ: *They worked out the 120 chars threshold. What do we do now? "Make it 130"* ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blacklists are stupid and should only *warn* about *potentially* unacceptable content instead of completely disallowing it. No word blacklist has ever stopped anyone from posting naughty words.

That being said...

### Good advice

Make your comment longer than 120 characters.

### Bad advice

Replace characters in your comment with random Unicode characters that look similar.